# jeditable form with symfony2

Tags: jquery-plugins, symfony, jeditable

I'm using the jQuery plugin jeditable in my template: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
So, if I click on an editable element, the text changes to a form with a textfield and a submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit').editable('{{ path('group_update', { id: group.id }) }}', { 
        type    : 'textarea',
        submit  : 'OK'
    });
});
</script>
```

And in the body I have something like that:

```
<div class="edit">{{ group.name }}</div>
```

But there is a problem. When I click on the submit-button, nothing happens. No forwarding to my action (in fact there is no reaction).

What can I do?

Comment: I got no errors. No problems in rendering, everything looks like it should look.

Comment: Are you sure that action is hit? Is you place var_dump($id) inside your action - will it output something?

Comment: I already tried that, but nothing happened. The page doesn't even refresh, there is no reaction when I click the submit-button.

Comment: The page should not be refreshed, actually... The thing is that you edit the page without refreshing.

Comment: Yeah, but the action isn't called. There is no output, when I try echo or var_dump etc.

Comment: Try also `{{ url() }}` instead of `{{ path() }}`

Comment: Doesn't work too. When the template is rendered, the correct url is rendered: app_dev.php/group/1/update

Comment: Now, I tried to do some random doctrine-commands in the action. It seems like the action is executed, but the outputs are not rendered. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: This plugin does not rely on output. It just keeps DOM as it is, but sends data to controller.

Comment: Do you know how I can get the submitted data in the executed action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you need to handle data received from your action, you should submit the data to function instead of URL.

Example below is taken from the [documentation](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

```
 $('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) { 
     console.log(this);
     console.log(value);
     console.log(settings);
     return(value);
 }, { 
 type    : 'textarea',
 submit  : 'OK',
```

});

You can pass data to your function, which will make an AJAX call to your action and process all received data in a way you need

Comment: Thank you, now I have 1 problem left ;) .. When the form is submitted, the datebase is edited. After that, the text is displayed again. The problem is that the previous value is displayed, not the new value. How can I fix that?